# Find the index of the last word character ( e.g.: /\w/ ) in a string with JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a simple, ***fast*** way to find the index of the last, non-underscore, word character (i.e. digit or letter) in a string.

**Example:**

`lastCharacterIndex("hello world!");
=> 10`

Comment: You could just loop the characters of the string from the end to beginning and check with its ascii number if its a digit or letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `RegExp.lastIndex`:

```
s = "hello world!";
re = /[a-z0-9](?=\W*$)/gi; // global flag is important
re.exec(s);

index = re.lastIndex-1; // 10
```

Comment: Accepted. I thank all of you for your answers, each one worked perfectly, but @anubhava's was the fastest after 10,000 iterations.

Comment: Its probably not the fastest, it uses a lookahead and starts from the beginning of the line. The fastest is probably when it starts at the end of the line with a greedy match.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function lastCharacterIndex(str){
    var m = str.match(/\w[^\w]*$/);
    return null===m ? -1 : str.lastIndexOf(m[0]);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a letter or digit followed only by non-letter non-digits, and take the index of the match (if there is a match).

```
var s = "hello world!";
var re = /[a-z\d][\W_]*$/i;
var match = re.exec(s);
var index = match ? match.index : -1;
alert(index);  // 10
```

The match of a RegExp in JS is an Array, but it has two extra non-integer properties: "index" and "input".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the index of it, but the last alphanum should be the last
character of match 0 using this

```
 [\S\s]*[^\W_]
```